# Pro*C: get n sequence increments in one select (with host arrays)

Tags: c, oracle

I have the following loop in Pro*C (not compiled yet, but you get the idea):

```
EXEC SQL BEGIN DECLARE SECTION;
    unsigned* vec;
    unsigned n;
    unsigned next_id;
EXEC SQL END DECLARE SECTION;

n = /* some input value */;
vec = (unsigned*)malloc(n* sizeof(unsigned));

for (unsigned i = 0; i < n; ++i) {
  EXEC SQL SELECT myseq.nextval INTO :next_id FROM dual;
  vec[i] = next_id;
}
```

Is there a way to use a `select for :n blablabla into :vec from dual`, so that I get `myseq.nextval` executed `n` times (giving me `n` rows with incremental `nextval`s) but in a single query?

Any approach is valid (from PL/SQL blocks to dynamic queries) as far as I don't have to write any loop (I know how to do it with loops/cursor etc, but I'm looking for something more "direct").

Comment: No, I don't think  so

Comment: you can try this sql :select myseq.nextval from dual connect by level<:n+1 (It works in sqlplus, so it should also work in pro*c.

Comment: @gsalem the problem is the "store" part. I want to do something like: `exec sql for :n select myseq.nextval into :vec from dual connect by level < :n + 1`, but Pro*C doesn't allow using host variables into the `connect by` part.

Comment: Try to tell pro*c not to parse the sql (common_parser=yes or something like that)